# How delete the content of a directory in Centos

Tags: linux, centos5, directory

I need to delete all the content of a folder in CentOS but not the folder itself.

For example: I have a folder named "MYFOLDER" which contains subfolders FOLD_1, FOLD_2, FOLD_3, FOLD_4... etc , and some files. I need to delete all these folders and files but not the container  folder MYFOLDER. I need this directory to direct the results of a previous process.

I tried with the `rm -rf`  command, but this delete the container folder too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Delete the contents of the folder instead.

```
rm -r MYFOLDER/*
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't hidden files/directories within MYFOLDER

Comment: @tylerl: It does if you set `shopt -s dotglob` first.

Comment: This requires you to manually approve y/n descending into each subdirectory, which is a complete waste of time.  The correct command would handle all that automatically so you don't get stuck with 50 prompts.

Comment: `rm -R /path/to/myfolder/*` is the correct syntax to avoid excessive requests to approve deletion of every file and subfolder.  Note the capital `R`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
rm -r MYFOLDER/{.[^.],.??*}
```

This deletes also the hidden files and folders. If you have too many files in the MYFOLDER directory, then you should run instead:

```
ls MYFOLDER/{.[^.],.??*}|xargs rm -r
```

Comment: I have over 500k files inside my `meta/` directory, so I wanted to try the xargs alternative, however i get these error messages: 

`ls: cannot access meta/.[^.]: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access meta/.??*: No such file or directory
rm: missing operand`

Comment: Make sure you are using `bash` shell. The shell must support "Brace Expansion" and "Regular Expressions" for file patterns.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way, in my opinion, is to delete the entire directory,  including itself, and then recreate the folder. There are situations when this is not a good solution (such a unattended scripts or more complex pipelines), but you didn't specify why you didn't want to delete the folder.

```
rm -rf foldername
mkdir foldername
```

Oops. You did specify (i reread your post). Well,still, deleting and recreating can work. Especially if you chain commands together, like

```
rm -rf foldername && mkdir foldername
```

Or

```
rm -rf foldername; mkdir foldername
```

Comment: Sometimes you do not have permission in the parent folder or you want to preserve certain attributes you are unaware of. E.g. you can not delete your home folder as non root user, but you can remove anything under it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
cd MYFOLDER
find . | rm -rf
```

This deletes hidden files (the ones starting with a dot), too.

Comment: This will delete MYFOLDER too.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rm -r -f filename` its working with CentOS 6.x

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend this alternative (it also removes files with spaces in names):

```
find MYFOLDER/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f
```